# 403 error while calling NetSuite Restlet from Node.js

Tags: node.js, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to create a Customer record in NetSuite by calling a deployed NetSuite Restlet script from Node.js. I am getting a 403 error in response. I am able to call the script successfully through [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info). I am not sure what's the issue when called from Node.js, because the authorization part in the code looks correct. Here's the code in Node.js:

```
function upsertUsingRestlet(body, callbackFn) {

  const baseUrl = `https://${NETSUITE_ACCOUNT_ID}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=${SCRIPT_ID}&deploy=${DEPLOYMENT_ID}`;
  const oauthSignatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA256';
  const oauthVersion = '1.0';
  const oauthNonce = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  const oauthTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  const oauthParameters = {
    oauth_consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
    oauth_nonce: oauthNonce,
    oauth_timestamp: oauthTimestamp,
    oauth_signature_method: oauthSignatureMethod,
    oauth_version: '1.0'
  };

  const sortedParameters = Object.keys(oauthParameters)
    .sort()
    .map((key) => `${key}=${oauthParameters[key]}`)
    .join('&');

  const signatureBaseString = `POST&${encodeURIComponent(baseUrl)}&${encodeURIComponent(sortedParameters)}`;
  const signingKey = `${CONSUMER_SECRET}&${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}`;
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingKey);
  hmac.update(signatureBaseString);
  let oauthSignature = hmac.digest('base64');
  oauthSignature = encodeURIComponent(oauthSignature);

  const headers = {
    'Prefer': 'transient',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `OAuth realm="${REALM}",oauth_nonce="${oauthNonce}",oauth_signature_method="${oauthSignatureMethod}",oauth_consumer_key="${CONSUMER_KEY}",oauth_token="${ACCESS_TOKEN}",oauth_timestamp="${oauthTimestamp}",oauth_version="${oauthVersion}",oauth_signature="${oauthSignature}"`
  };

  fetch(baseUrl, {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': headers,
    'body': body,
    'redirect': 'follow'
  })
    .then((response) => response)
    .then((data) => {
      callbackFn(data.status);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error upsertOperation:', error);
    });
}
```

In Netsuite, View login and Audit trail - I see the error in Detail column as InvalidSignature.

However, the same authorization is working successfully when I call a netsuite [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API using the above code. The only difference was that it was a [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request instead of [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29). So, I am not sure why it is not working with Restlet.

Restlet script deployment screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77595304/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: Can that answer be removed by moderators? I don't want it to reduce the visibility/interest in my question from the other members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following changes:

1. Added script and deploy in oauthParameters
2. baseUrl while creating the signature should be without the parameters.

Rest everything remains the same.

Here's the updated code for reference:-

```
function upsertUsingRestlet(body, callbackFn) {

  const baseUrl = `https://${NETSUITE_ACCOUNT_ID}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl`;
const baseUrlWithParameters = baseUrl + `?script=${SCRIPT_ID}&deploy=${DEPLOYMENT_ID}`;
  const oauthSignatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA256';
  const oauthVersion = '1.0';
  const oauthNonce = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  const oauthTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  const oauthParameters = {
    script: SCRIPT_ID,
    oauth_consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
    oauth_nonce: oauthNonce,
    oauth_timestamp: oauthTimestamp,
    oauth_signature_method: oauthSignatureMethod,
    oauth_version: '1.0',
    deploy: SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID
  };

  const sortedParameters = Object.keys(oauthParameters)
    .sort()
    .map((key) => `${key}=${oauthParameters[key]}`)
    .join('&');

  const signatureBaseString = `POST&${encodeURIComponent(baseUrl)}&${encodeURIComponent(sortedParameters)}`;
  const signingKey = `${CONSUMER_SECRET}&${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}`;
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingKey);
  hmac.update(signatureBaseString);
  let oauthSignature = hmac.digest('base64');
  oauthSignature = encodeURIComponent(oauthSignature);

  const headers = {
    'Prefer': 'transient',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `OAuth realm="${REALM}",oauth_nonce="${oauthNonce}",oauth_signature_method="${oauthSignatureMethod}",oauth_consumer_key="${CONSUMER_KEY}",oauth_token="${ACCESS_TOKEN}",oauth_timestamp="${oauthTimestamp}",oauth_version="${oauthVersion}",oauth_signature="${oauthSignature}"`
  };

  fetch(baseUrlWithParameters, {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': headers,
    'body': body,
    'redirect': 'follow'
  })
    .then((response) => response)
    .then((data) => {
      callbackFn(data.status);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error upsertOperation:', error);
    });
}
```